# $\otimes$-products of global types in $\text{RCF}$

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

I'm struggling to understand a remark in Pierre Simon's [book](http://www.normalesup.org/%7Esimon/book.html) on NIP theories. Let $T$ be a complete theory and $\mathfrak{U}\models T$ a monster model. Suppose $p(x),q(y)\in S(\mathfrak{U})$ are global types with distinct free variables, and that $p$ is $E$-invariant for some small subset $E\subset\mathfrak{U}$. Then the product type $p(x)\otimes q(y)$ in the free variables $xy$ is defined by taking $\phi(x,y,c)\in p\otimes q$ if and only if there exists some $b$ realizing $q|_{Ec}(y)$ and such that $\phi(x,b,c)\in p$; this is well-defined by $E$-invariance of $p$. Simon says that $p$ and $q$ "commute" if $p(x)\otimes q(y)=q(y)\otimes p(x)$.

Exercise 2.22 has us show that, if $T=\text{DLO}$ and $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ are $1$-types, then $p$ and $q$ commute provided that $p$ and $q$ are inequivalent. I've done this without trouble, but I'm a bit perplexed by a subsequent remark:

> This is no longer true in $\text{RCF}$: if $p$ and $q$ are two invariant $1$-types which concentrate on definable cuts (either $\pm\infty$ or $a^{\pm}$), then they do not commute.

I'm struggling to see why this is the case. By quantifier elimination, a global $1$-type $p(x)\in S(\mathfrak{U})$ is uniquely determined by the $<$-cut of $\mathfrak{U}$ it represents, and the data of whether or not the equation $f=0$ lies in $p$ for each polynomial $f\in\mathfrak{U}[x]$. Since polynomials over a field have finitely many roots, if $p$ contains an equation $f=0$ then it is an algebraic type and hence has all possible realizations already in $\mathfrak{U}$. In particular, if $p(x),q(y)$ are distinct $1$-types that are not realized in $\mathfrak{U}$, then (i) they must represent different cuts in $\mathfrak{U}$, and (ii) we will have that $p(x)\otimes q(y)$ contains $f(x,y)\neq 0$ for each $f\in\mathfrak{U}[x,y]$. Furthermore, if I'm not mistaken, $p(x)\otimes q(y)\supset p(x)\cup q(y)$, so the only possible way for $p(x)\otimes q(y)$ and $q(y)\otimes p(x)$ to differ is if one of them contains $x<y$ and the other contains $x\geqslant y$. But $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ represent different cuts, so without loss of generality there exists $c\in\mathfrak{U}$ such that $x<c\in p(x)$ and $c<y\in q(y)$, and then necessarily $x<y$ lies in both $p(x)\otimes q(y)$ and $q(y)\otimes p(x)$, again since each of these types contains $p(x)\cup q(y)$. So it's unclear to me how the circumstances described by Simon can arise; does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Suppose $p(x)$ is the type at $\infty$ and $q(y)$ is the type at $-\infty$. Now consider the formula $x\leq -y$. Is this in $p(x)\otimes q(y)$? What about $q(y)\otimes p(x)$?

The point is that in RCF, all the definable cuts are non-orthogonal in the sense that any realization of one definable cut contains in its definable closure (over the model) realizations of all the other definable cuts.

Comment: ahhh, I didn't think about the ways in which the field structure could interact with the ordering; thank you! just to make sure I'm understanding your latter comment, is this for example how one might argue if $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ represent cuts that correspond to elements of $U$ rather than $\pm\infty$?

suppose $a_0,b_0\in U$ are such that $x<c\in p(x)$ iff $c\geqslant a_0$ and $y<c\in q(y)$ iff $c\geqslant b_0$ for all $c\in U$. now I think $p$ and $q$ should be invariant over $A:=\{a_0,b_0\}$.

Comment: the formula $x+b_0> y+a_0$ lies in $p(x)\otimes q(y)$, since for any realization $b$ of $q|_{A}$ we have $b<b_0$, hence $a_0+(b-b_0)<a_0$, hence $x>b+a_0-b_0\in p(x)$. on the other hand, the formula $x+b_0<y+a_0$ lies in $q(y)\otimes p(x)$, since for any realization $a$ of $p|_{A}$ we have $a<a_0$, hence $b_0+(a-a_0)<b_0$, hence $y>a+b_0-a_0\in p(x)$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom That's right! And you can make the type "just above" $a_0$ interact with the type "just below" $b_0$ with a judicious use of additive inverse, and make either of these interact with the types at $\pm\infty$ with a judicious use of multiplicative inverse.

Comment: hello! sorry to circle back to this question, but there was something additional I was wondering. it's clear to me why every definable cut is of one of those forms: by Dedekind completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, $\text{RCF}$ proves that every set definable with parameters and bounded above has a supremum. but I'm wondering, are there any non-definable cuts in $\mathfrak{U}$? I really strongly suspect yes, but I'm struggling to come up with a way of concretely constructing any... maybe is there some kind of compactness or cardinality argument?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom How about the cut whose lower half is $\{r\mid r<s\text{ for some }s\in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: Oh that's wonderful, thank you!! Am I right in thinking that the same argument shows that no infinite $\aleph_1$-saturated linear order $O$ (not necessarily dense) can be Dedekind-complete? Since we can find a countably infinite subset $A\subset O$ with no maximum element, and then take the cut whose bottom half is $\{b\in O:b<a\text{ for some }a\in A\}$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom That's exactly right. It's interesting - Dedekind-completeness and saturation seem like similar principles, but they're incompatible!